# Will Cafetto cleaning tablets work with Sage Dual Boiler machine?

Tags: espresso-machine, cleaning

Will this [Cafetto cleaning tablets](https://www.hasbean.co.uk/collections/cleaning-products/products/cafetto-home-eco-espresso-machine-cleaning-tablets) work with my Sage Dual Boiler espresso machine (the "by Heston" range)?

Comment: For reference for people outside of the UK, this model is the Breville Dual Boiler BES920XL as it is only known as Sage series by Heston Blumenthal in the UK.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I use aftermarket cleaning tablets on my Infuser and Profitec. I haven't used the Cafetto branded ones but they're all essentially the same for backflushing.

Just follow the normal backflush regiment and use these tablets instead of the breville ones and you'll be fine. Personally I use Urnex Cafiza tablets, but again, they're essentially the same thing.